# Form Based login in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

I am new to AngularJS and gone through their tutorial and got a feel for it

I have a backend for my project ready where each of the REST endpoints needs to be authenticated.it will give 401 response when the user is not authenticated for every request.

And due to this a default login pop of browser is opening.And i want to open login.html instead of that default browser pop-up.

Is there any way to do this. I saw here and here but did not understand how to use them.
so be kind to explain it.

thanks

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: This is issue on the server side configurations. What is the hosting platform.

Comment: I'm developping an application in AngularJS for the front-end and JavaEE for the back-end. In my AngularJS application I try to access a REST resource provided by my back-end. this resource is protected with JAAS, so only authenticated users can access the resource.

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate a little more about your problem. As which kind of browser popup came. Does this come from server side? or you implement the popup at frontend other than login.html?

Comment: it is coming from server side.i am using JAX-RS Security at the server side.I followed this link for that.  http://cxf.apache.org/docs/secure-jax-rs-services.html

Comment: Then obviously you need to handle that logic at front-end, so you can display login.html in case of unauthorized access.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand whether you've already implemented the login solution. If you've not, you should take a look at this amazing James Ward article: [Securing Single Page Apps and REST Services](http://www.jamesward.com/2013/05/13/securing-single-page-apps-and-rest-services) . That authentication pattern is implemented at [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http).